# How to make press and hold button to Start a timer?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to make a android timer app. The timer starts when we press a button and hold it and stops when releasing a button. Please tell me the method that functions the same. I am following an example http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/handler/android-timer-example/ to make a timer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

override onTouch listener to the button with your timer logic

```
findViewById(R.id.btn_add).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    // start your timer

                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                   // stop your timer.

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this could help you:

```
       button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           switch (event.getAction()) {
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                   // Button is pressed
                   break;
               }
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                   // Button is not pressed
               }
           }
           return true;
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     findViewById(R.id.btn1_add).setOnTouchListener(new                                                             
         View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                // start tiemr

            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
               // stop timer.

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

void    setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener l)
Register a callback to be invoked when a touch event is sent to this view.

You can have a look at [this-](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)