# Press and hold event for a button in source code

Tags: android

i have a button. Instead of it clicked, i need to record when button in pressed and hold. when it is released it shud stop working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make press and hold button to Start a timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31089275/how-to-make-press-and-hold-button-to-start-a-timer)

Comment: you need to work on the touch events by implementing `View.OnTouchListener`. Here refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17316038/4878972)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

```
findViewById(R.id.btn).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                // button pressed

            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
               // button relased.

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks alot this worked well. Now one doubt on this. when this button being presssed i have to show a counter running on a text view , when the button isreleased  counter should stop. if we press button again it should start from the last count